# Sanitizing url parameters

Tags: php, security, xss

I ran a pentest on my app and it should an XSS issue.  Essentially, I could do a url like the following and it would give me a popup

```
https://test.com/index.php?id=12345'><script>alert(1)</script>
```

So I have implemented something which I hope resolves this issue.  At the top of the page I do

```
$_GET['id'] = urlencode($_GET['id']);
```

Within the page content, I might then have a link to another page like so

```
<a href="https://test.com/page2.php?id=<?php print $_REQUEST['id']; ?>">Link</a>
```

When I now test the page, no pop up is displayed.  The pentest is also clear.  However, someone else in another location is trying it and they still get the popup.  I just wanted to make sure that what I have done is ok?

Additionally, when I view the link in firebug, I see the link with the script part.  Should this not be displaying as sanitized within firebug?

Any information appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

I would set it to an intermediate variable, since you're using the `$_REQUEST` array later instead of `$_GET`

```
$id = urlencode(htmlentities($_GET['id']));
```

and then later

```
<a href="https://test.com/page2.php?id=<?php print $id; ?>">Link</a>
```